# Add additional service to buy on product page

Tags: product, configurable-product, product-list

I want to add some additional services to our productpage.
By default people buy product with manufacturer warranty, but I want to add an additional service.

So that people can buy the default manufacturer warranty or 2 additional insurance packages.

All our current products (15000+) are simple products, so we can not easily switch this to configurable products.

What is the best way to add this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Custom Options* available in Product tabs.
Following links will be helpful:

- http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-product-option-and-its-use-case-in-magento/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HbSH2cPrdo

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is it also possible to apply this to many products? And I would like to add more text to the radiobuttons. Not only the option but also an explanation. How can I fix that?

Comment: Yes, you can apply this to as many product you want, but that needs to be done individually! And if you want it to be done for every product at a time, then a manual coding/Script need to written.

Magento offers only Title for Custom Product Options, you can write your description there, or if you want a separate field for explanation, then customization will be required.